# Why .Traceback splits long strings on two parts?

Tags: r, debugging, traceback

I have faced with the strange behavior of the `.Traceback` object in R.

When I try to print the short error message, it is ok and the `.Traceback[[1]]` has the one element. But when I try to print very long string, the `.Traceback[[1]]` object becomes the list of two elements. Look:

```
>stop(paste("short", "string"))
Error: short string
>.Traceback
[[1]]
[1] "stop(paste(\"short\", \"string\"))"

>stop(paste("very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong", "string"))
Error: very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong string
>.Traceback
[[1]]
[1] "stop(paste(\"very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong\", "
[2] "    \"string\"))"
```

Could you help me to figure it out? I'm really confused by this unintended behavior.

Comment: The spillover into the new character vector element happens when the total  # char in `paste` goes from 52 to 53. Also note that there is only 1 pairlist element in both cases; merely more character elements within the 1 element in the long text case.

Comment: @Hack-R I guess it can be changed in the `options` right

Comment: @Hack-R I am not completely sure about that

Answer (score 1):

> Could you help me to figure it out?

It seems to be affected by `options(width)`

```r
stop(paste("very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong", "string"))
.Traceback
#R [[1]]
#R [1] "stop(paste(\"very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong\", "
#R [2] "    \"string\"))" 

options(width = 9001)
stop(paste("very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong", "string"))
.Traceback
#R [[1]]
#R [1] "stop(paste(\"very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong\", " "    \"string\"))"
```

This is not clear from the help page though. It is though written in `help(".Traceback")` that

> The calls may print on more than one line, ...

Do also notice from from `help(".Traceback")`

> **Warning**
>
> It is undocumented where `.Traceback` is stored nor that it is visible, and this is subject to change.

so likely use `traceback()` instead

```
tr <- traceback()
all.equal(tr, .Traceback)
#R [1] TRUE
```